# Rust target i586-unknown-linux-gun on Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit

Tags: ubuntu, rust, cross-compiling

I'm running a Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit and I need to build some rust project target some i586 arch devices. I know rust support `target i586-unknown-linux-gnu` but I don't know how to install related `gcc` and use it to compile my rust project.

When I check `/usr/lib/gcc` there is only one `x86_64-linux-gnu`. Which package should I install to compile target `i586` on my os.

Comment: are you sure you need i586? you'll be hard pressed finding anything but i386 in most package stores for 32bit. but regardless, you want gcc-multilib and the related architectures

Comment: @haelmic `i586-unknown-linux-gnu` is actually listed as a tier 2 platform on the [Platform Support](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html) page. The only `i386` target there is `i386-apple-ios`. However, it might be fine to use a GCC that targets `i386` (or not, an `i386` linker might choke on `i586` objects).

Comment: `uname -m` showed my `i586` so I guess I really need `i586`. The cpu is `Intel Quark SoC X1000`. I already installed `gcc-multilib` but I don't know the correct step to link it in Rust. It only check `/usr/lib/gcc` folder by default.